# ¿Cómo añadir otros registros de tablas en reportes de excel?

Tags: php, sql, yii

mi duda es la siguiente.

Estoy usando yii para generar los reportes en excel a través de su controlador. Uso este método `findAllbySql` para hacer el SQL a travÉs de un modelo. Me ejecuto perfectamente el SQL.

Ahora, genero el reporte con la consulta SQL

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tabla1 
       join tabla2 on tabla1.idcampo1=tabla2.idcampo2 
       join tabla3 on tabla3.idcampo3=tabla1.idcampo1;
```

Cuando me genera el reporte, solo me sale los datos de la `tabla3` y no los de la `tabla1` y `tabla2`.

Nota: Los campos de la tabla 1 a la 3 tienen el mismo nombre por ejemplo. campo: `cod_sudebip` y `nombre`.

Comment: ¿Has intentado poner alias a los campos, para que se llamen diferente?